# Code / Test coverage tool for cocoapods?

Tags: ios, code-coverage, cocoapods, test-coverage

Is there a tool out there that can check the coverage of a cocoapod repository?

I've taken a look at codeclimate, gcov, gcovr, [XcodeCoverage](https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage), [cocoapods-coverage](https://github.com/viteinfinite/cocoapods-coverage), but none of them will check the coverage of the cocoapod files, just the default project's classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pull request adding coverage to a [CocoaPods library](https://github.com/orta/ORStackView/pull/29)

Comment: @Wow. Thanks for the answer. I love that I can use coveralls. Also, THANK YOU FOR ARANALYTICS! I have my entire company using your library for all of our projects.

Comment: Rockin, glad to be of use twice :)

Comment: Sorry, but could you expand on this? From what I can tell running slather like that would generate coverage data for the main project only (the main project for that repo, that is). Is there a way to gather coverage data for the Pods in a workspace? Perhaps I should create a new question.